# How to invoke any app without losing its previous state?

Tags: android, android-intent

i am able to launch any apps which are on emulator screen from my app just with the help of their package names but after launching those apps if i press home button and if i launch the same app from my app it's being launched from initial state not where i used and left that before...for that i tried setting the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` on the intent which is used to launch the app but there is no effect...
Here is my code

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent=packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get used of FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, because you're rewriting the intent object. Fix your code to:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope, this helps.